# JavaMailSender not sending mail if from address is yahoo.com/yahoo.co.in

Tags: email, spring-mvc, smtp, jakarta-mail, yahoo-mail

Please see my configuration.

```
<beans:bean id="mailSender" class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <beans:property name="host" value="${SMTP_HOST}"/>
    <beans:property name="port" value="${SMTP_PORT}"/>
     <beans:property name="javaMailProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="mail.smtp.auth">${SMTP_AUTH}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="mail.smtp.host">${SMTP_HOST}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="mail.smtp.port">${SMTP_PORT}</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="mail.smtp.from">${BOUNCED_MAIL_ID}</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="username" value="${SMTP_USERNAME}"/>
    <beans:property name="password" value="${SMTP_PASSWORD}"/>
</beans:bean>
```

and i have a property file with the below data and my own SMTP server.

```
SMTP_HOST=ab.hexatech.com
SMTP_PORT=25
SMTP_AUTH=true
SMTP_USERNAME=info@hexatech.com
SMTP_PASSWORD=password
BOUNCED_MAIL_ID=demo%40hexatechsolutions.com
BOUNCED_MAIL_PWD=info123%40123
```

This is my java code.

```
try{
        final MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        final MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message);

        helper.setFrom("m4munavar@yahoo.co.in");
        helper.setSubject("subject");


        setReciepientTypes(to, cc, bcc, helper);
        final BodyPart bodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        bodyPart.setContent(mergeTemplateIntoString(msg, templateLoc, model), "text/html");
        final Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(bodyPart);
        if(attachment != null)
        {
            final MimeBodyPart attachPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            attachPart.attachFile(attachment);
            multipart.addBodyPart(attachPart);
        }

        if(header!=null && !header.isEmpty()){
            for (final String headername :header.keySet()) {
                message.setHeader(headername, header.get(headername).toString());
            }
        }
        message.setContent(multipart);
        mailSender.send(message);
    }catch(final Exception exception){
        LogMessage.log(exception.getMessage(), exception);
        throw  new ApplicationException(exception.getMessage());
    }
```

It is sending mail if the from address is anything other than mail address containing yahoo.com or yahoo.co.in

Please help me out to figure out the issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your SMTP server is probably configured to prevent you from impersonating another user.  That's a good thing.

If you want to send as a Yahoo user, why aren't you using the Yahoo mail server?

Comment: I have my own SMTP mail server. But the application is used by customers having different mail Ids.

Comment: Then the application needs to be configured to use their mail servers/